# Laravel Orchid: How can the post entry in the database be retrieved from in the PostEditScreen.php?

Tags: database, laravel

Laravel Orchid: How can the post entry in the database be retrieved from in the PostEditScreen.php?

In a function in the PostEditScreen.php, how can the entry in the database that is being referred to by the PostEditScreen be accessed?

`Post::find($post.id)` is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Query data.
 *
 * @param Post $post
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function query(Post $post): array
{
    // This will already be a record of your model.
}
```

Or you can do it explicitly

```
/**
 * Query data.
 *
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function query(int $id): array
{
   Post::find($id)
}
```

This is stated in the laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding